# CakePHP (2.1) Media Plugin - Multi File Upload

Tags: file, cakephp, plugins, upload, media

I'm using the cakephp media plugin in my project using the monolithic style attachments table, i.e. all the attachments go in the one table with foreign_key, model, group etc. saved with the file details. So my model looks like:

```
class ProjectProfile extends AppModel {

var $name = 'ProjectProfile';
var $useDbConfig = 'default';
var $useTable = 'project_profiles';
var $actsAs = array('Media.Transfer', 'Media.Generator');

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'pjID'
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
      'Photo' => array(
          'className' => 'Media.Attachment',
          'order' => 'Photo.basename, Photo.id',
          'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
          'conditions' => array('Photo.model' => 'ProjectProfile', 'Photo.group' => 'Photo'),
          'dependent' => true)
  );
```

Then a saveAll in the controller when saving my record saves the attached file.

This all works fine, however I'd really like to be able to upload multiple files at once, which the plugin does support by doing this in the form:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Photo.0.model', array('value' => 'Photo'));
echo $this->Form->input('Photo.0.file', array('type' => 'file');
echo $this->Form->hidden('Photo.1.model', array('value' => 'Photo'));
echo $this->Form->input('Photo.1.file', array('type' => 'file');
echo $this->Form->hidden('Photo.2.model', array('value' => 'Photo'));
echo $this->Form->input('Photo.2.file', array('type' => 'file');
```

But I think you'd agree that's a bit cumbersome to have to click browse for each individual file. The simplist method I could see to to allow multiple file uploads was to use the HTML5 multiple file section option - http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/veganista/2012/01/31/html_5_multiple_file_upload_with_cake :

```
echo $this->Form->input('files.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));
```

This allows you to shift click in the file browser to select multiple files then puts the files into an array to save... however, this field format isn't handled by the media plugin. Also, there'd be no way to add the model, group etc. fields on the save as far as I could see.

So, does anybody know how I can handle multi file uploads with the media plugin using the monolithic model? I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Will this CakePHP 2.x plugin - [AjaxMultiUpload](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload) - work for you? I think that does exactly what you need it to.